# Pivot Tables of Counts in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
  Col X    Col Y
class 1    cat 1
class 2    cat 1
class 3    cat 2
class 2    cat 3
```

that I want to transform into:

```
         cat 1  cat 2  cat 3
class 1      1      0      0
class 2      1      0      1
class 3      0      1      0
```

where the values are value counts. How do I do it?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Here are couple of ways to reshape your data `df`

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
     Col X  Col Y
0  class 1  cat 1
1  class 2  cat 1
2  class 3  cat 2
3  class 2  cat 3
```

**1)** Using [`pd.crosstab()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
In [28]: pd.crosstab(df['Col X'], df['Col Y'])
Out[28]:
Col Y    cat 1  cat 2  cat 3
Col X
class 1      1      0      0
class 2      1      0      1
class 3      0      1      0
```

**2)** Or, use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `'Col X','Col Y'` with `unstack` over `Col Y`, then fill `NaNs` with zeros.

```
In [29]: df.groupby(['Col X','Col Y']).size().unstack('Col Y', fill_value=0)
Out[29]:
Col Y    cat 1  cat 2  cat 3
Col X
class 1      1      0      0
class 2      1      0      1
class 3      0      1      0
```

**3)** Or, use [`pd.pivot_table()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `index=Col X`, `columns=Col Y`

```
In [30]: pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Col X'], columns=['Col Y'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
Out[30]:
Col Y    cat 1  cat 2  cat 3
Col X
class 1      1      0      0
class 2      1      0      1
class 3      0      1      0
```

**4)** Or, use `set_index` with `unstack`

```
In [492]: df.assign(v=1).set_index(['Col X', 'Col Y'])['v'].unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[492]:
Col Y    cat 1  cat 2  cat 3
Col X
class 1      1      0      0
class 2      1      0      1
class 3      0      1      0
```

Comment: Thanks John - that was incredibly helpful, especially providing different possibilities!  I didn't even think of the cross tab possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the comparison of all three.  I default to groupby, and often see pivot_table used.

Comment: came across this because I was trying to figure out the difference between groupby and pivot_table and when to use which. Your answer was certainly helpful. Do you know of somehow easily comprehensible information on the different concepts? cheers

Comment: Warning: the last method (`set_index` and `unstack`) does not generally work: it fails when there is a duplicate line in the original data.

Answer (score 1):

Since pandas 1.1.0, `value_counts()` can be called on a dataframe. So another way is to count each pairs of Col X-Col Y values and unstack the counts.

```py
table = df[['Col X', 'Col Y']].value_counts().rename_axis([None, None]).unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image: transformation]