# How change I change what I have into a python map function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, lambda

I have a dataframe where each row has an author(news channel), the title of the article, and number of comments on that article.

Basically, I want to calculate the number of comments on each article. I currently have the following code, but I want to factor it.

```
# CSV of news articles, with authors, articles, and comments
df = pd.read_csv('articles.csv')

# Counts per author
art_count = df['AUTHOR'].value_counts()

# Calculate # of comments per article
def comment_sum(df, channel, channel_name, target):
    # ex) sum(df[df['AUTHOR'] == 'NYTIMES']['COMMENTS'])
    return sum(df[df[channel] == channel_name][target])

# Calculate # of comments
com_count = []
for newspaper in art_count.index:
    com_count.append(comment_sum(df,'AUTHOR',newspaper,'COMMENTS'))
```

I feel as if I can simplify my code, without declaring a method, by using a map and lambda function, but I'm unsure how to go about it.

Comment: did you hear of groupby in python? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679467/pivot-tables-or-group-by-for-pandas check this one out!

Comment: `df.groupby(['AUTHOR','article'])['COMMENTS'].sum()`? ('article' is the column of articles)

Comment: If either of you post as an answer, I can select the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.groupby(['AUTHOR','article'])['COMMENTS'].sum()` for posterity, as @ansev has answered in the comments.