# How to groupby df with multiple entries per item, adding columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to reconfigure a df that entries based on Location and year but with multiple entries. I need them all grouped by Location and year so I can process it.

Location  Year  Type  Value
1         1     A     1.3
1         1     B     2.1
1         1     C     3.6
2         1     A     1.7
2         1     B     2.8
2         1     C     0.9
...

into

Location  Year  ValueA  ValueB  ValueC
1         1    1.3     2.1     3.6
2         1     1.7     2.8     0.9

Comment: 1. Here is how to make a good post JosephFife (your post is not a good one) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples 2. Here is a good StackOverflow question on groupby that should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum

Comment: Should the year in the second row of the second table be 2, not 1?

Comment: Thanks, first time posting, I think I clarified it now

Comment: Thanks @JosephFife for making the question much better. I provided an answer. Hope it helps. here is another good post about the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960338/pandas-difference-between-pivot-and-pivot-table-why-is-only-pivot-table-workin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally use a `pivot_table` as that's what I'm more comfortable with, but I think there are multiple ways to do this. Here is another useful post on pivot tables vs. groupby. Hope it helps [Pivot Tables or Group By for Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679467/pivot-tables-or-group-by-for-pandas)

Input (copy data before using pd.read_clipboard():

```
 Location Year Type Value
 1 1 A 1.3
 1 1 B 2.1
 1 1 C 3.6
 2 2 A 1.7
 2 2 B 2.8
 2 2 C 0.9
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_clipboard()
df=df.pivot_table(index=['Location', 'Year'], columns='Type', values='Value').reset_index()
df
```

Output:

```
Type Location Year A    B   C
0    1        1    1.3  2.1 3.6
1    2        2    1.7  2.8 0.9
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This really helps

Comment: @JosephFife no problem, since it is your first post, I just wanted to let you know that you can upvote / accept an answer if the post was helpful or if the answer answered your question.